# dlib.rectangle Failing expression was p.is_empty() == false

Tags: dlib

I am using Dlib by Davis King in Python, I'm using its Correlation tracker feature where I have to specify the rectangle on a frame which is read from my webcam

I am using Yolo v3 to get the coordinates of the detected object like Car or Person then pass them to `start_track` like this

`tracker = dlib.correlation_tracker()
 dlib_rect = dlib.rectangle(left, top, bottom, right) 
 tracker.start_track(frame, dlib_rect)`

I know my coordinates are right and if I just draw them without tracking, they are showing bounding boxes on the correct objects detected by Yolo v3 but when I am using them in the start_track method I get the following error

```
tracker.start_track(frame, dlib_rect)
RuntimeError:

Error detected at line 61.
Error detected in file e:\documents\projects\dlib\dlib\image_processing\correlation_tracker.h.
Error detected in function void __cdecl dlib::correlation_tracker::start_track<class dlib::numpy_image<struct dlib::rgb_pixel>>(const class dlib::numpy_image<struct dlib::rgb_pixel> &,const class dlib::drectangle &).

Failing expression was p.is_empty() == false.
         void correlation_tracker::start_track()
         You can't give an empty rectangle.
```

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to [Davis King himself for pointing out](https://github.com/davisking/dlib/issues/1339) I had the wrong parameter ordering

Rectangle should have been defined as

`dlib_rect = dlib.rectangle(left, top, right, bottom)`